# Read a file into an array using carriage return as delimiter (bash)

Tags: arrays, oracle, bash, sorting

I have a tnsnames.ora file with the following format:

```
ALIAS_NAME =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1823))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = alias_name)
    )
  )

ALIAS_NAME1=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1823))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = alias_name1)
    )
  )


ALIAS_NAME2 =
    (DESCRIPTION =
    (LOAD_BALANCE = ON)
    (FAILOVER = ON)
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1823))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1823))
     (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = ALIAS_NAME2)
      (FAILOVER_MODE =
        (TYPE = SELECT)
        (METHOD = BASIC)
        (RETRIES = 20)
        (DELAY = 1)
      )
    )
  )
```

I want to sort this file alphabetically based on the alias name, so I thought I'll read the file into an array separated by carriage returns, so that one element of the array looks like this:

```
ALIAS_NAME =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1823))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = alias_name)
    )
  )
```

Then I'll do a sort on the array. Is this possible? I tried doing something like this:

```
IFS='\n ' read -r -a array <<< file_name
```

but it didn't work. Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: What does sorting a text file have to do with Oracle?

Comment: Does it need to be in BASH? I can think of a way to do this in Python, but off the top of my head I cannot think of an easy way to do this in BASH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the file line by line

```
file_name=inputFile
current=-1
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line || [[ $line ]]; do
  regex='^[^ ]'
  if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
    # if it doesn't start with a space
    let current++
  fi
  (( current >= 0 )) || continue # discard garbage before the first alias
  [[ $line ]] || continue # skip empty lines
  array[current]=${array[current]}$'\n'$line
done < "$file_name"
declare -p array
```

You will then have an array containing the text you wanted.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005 for further reading on the subject.